# How to convert Julian date ignoring the year to Julian Day

Tags: vba, vb.net, julian-date

How do i convert day/Month to Julian Day in visual basic?
Formula for converting in other languages are also appreciated.

For e.g
Julian Day for 1 Feb=032

https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html

From research in the web ,most resolutions are converting the date with yyyy-mm-dd to julian date.

As the example above, i need to get value 032

Comment: Without the year, how will you handle leap year? By other languages do you mean languages other than English or other programming languages? If you can input a year, `DateTime.DayOfYear` might do the trick.

Comment: The number of days in the months of the year is the same as the gregorian calendar, but leap years differ slightly because it didn't have the 100 year exeption to leap years. So, as @Mary said, you will still need to include the year.

Comment: I mean given a year, month and day the Julian day is based on the link I gave with 3 digits values only,how do I go about doing that, the normal online Julian converter is based on date with more than 3 digit values after conversion.  By other language I mean any other programming languages as well as I just need to study the programming logic of converting.Any programming language will do but preferably vb6 the environment I am working on

Comment: To clarify your question, for the date March 1, 1900, should the result be 60 or 61?

Answer (score 0):

The .Net [JulianCalendar Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) exposes all methods needed to achieve your goal.  It is also COM visible, so you can reference it in a VBA project after adding a project reference to "mscorlib.dll".

In VB.Net the code would be:

```
Dim jc As New System.Globalization.JulianCalendar
' create a gregorian equivalent of the julian date: 1 Feb 2018
Dim gregoriaDateEquivalent As DateTime = jc.ToDateTime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
' = #2/14/2018 12:00:00 AM#
Dim dayOfYear As Int32 = jc.GetDayOfYear(gregoriaDateEquivalent)
' = 32
```

In VBA the code would be:

```
Dim jc As mscorlib.JulianCalendar
Set jc = New mscorlib.JulianCalendar

' create a gregorian equivalent of the julian date: 1 Feb 2018
Dim gregoriaDateEquivalent As Date
gregoriaDateEquivalent = jc.ToDateTime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
' = #2/14/2018
Dim dayOfYear As Long
dayOfYear = jc.GetDayOfYear(gregoriaDateEquivalent)
' = 32
```

Comment: @ThomasKoh, if it "works" consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add reference to mscorlib library
Under VB6,Project-References->Tick the mscorlib checkbox

Create this function method in the object that you ahve or otherwise create a sub procedure

```
Public Function JulianConverter() As String
        'MsgBox Fix(5.2), vbExclamation, App.Title
        'MsgBox Fix(5.6)
        Dim y As String
        Dim m As String
        Dim d As String
        Dim strDate As String
        Dim dateArray() As String


        strDate = Format(Now, "dd/MMM/yyyy")
        dateArray = Split(strDate, "/")
        d = dateArray(0)
        m = dateArray(1)
        y = dateArray(2)
        'Debug
        'MsgBox strDate

        'Convert to Integer
        y = Val(y)
        m = Val(m)
        d = Val(d)

        If m <= 2 Then
            y = y - 1
            m = m + 12
        End If

        'Dim A As Double
       ' Dim B As Double
        'Dim JD As Double

       ' A = CDbl(Fix(y / 100#))

        'B = 2 - A + Fix(A / 4)


        'JD = Fix(365.25 * (y + 4716)) + Fix(30.6001 * (m + 1)) + d + B - 1524.5
        'JulianConverter = CStr(JD) 'Convert to string

        Dim jc As mscorlib.JulianCalendar
Set jc = New mscorlib.JulianCalendar

' create a gregorian equivalent of the julian date: 1 Feb 2018
Dim gregoriaDateEquivalent As Date
gregoriaDateEquivalent = jc.ToDateTime(2018, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0)
' = #2/14/2018
Dim dayOfYear As Long
Dim dayOfYearS As String
Dim digitLength As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

dayOfYear = jc.GetDayOfYear(gregoriaDateEquivalent)

'Have to ensure 3 digits values
dayOfYearS = CStr(dayOfYear)

'Count number of Digits of string
digitLength = Len(dayOfYearS)

MsgBox "DigitLength" & digitLength, vbExclamation, App.Title

'If Digits length smaller than 3,add one 0 in front
If (digitLength < 3) Then
dayOfYearS = "0" & dayOfYearS
End If

JulianConverter = dayOfYearS

End Function
```

This will ensure the julian day will be 3 digits in value based on the current system date